# Converting string coming as day of week,Month dd,Year -time to date format yyyy-mm-dd time in XSLT 3.0

Tags: xml, xslt

I am using XSLT 3.0 and need help to Convert date string coming as(day of week,Month dd,Year -time) to date format yyyy-mm-dd time in xslt
For example- "Tuesday, January 29, 2018 - 10:10" should be converted to 2018-01-29 10:10 AM format. We have limitation and cant use `<msxsl:script>`.

Here is my xml input

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<rss version="2.0" xml:base="https://www.hhs.gov/rss/news.xml" xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/" xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom">
    <channel>
        <title>Latest News Releases</title>
        <link>https://www.hhs.gov/rss/news.xml</link>
        <description>HHS News Releases</description>
        <language>en</language>
        <atom:link href="https://www.hhs.gov/rss/news.xml" rel="self" type="application/rss+xml" />
        <item>
            <title>HHS Takes New Steps in Secretary Azar’s Value-Based Agenda</title>
            <link>https://www.hhs.gov/about/news/2018/04/24/hhs-takes-new-steps-in-secretary-azars-value-based-agenda.html</link>
            <pubDate>Tuesday, April 24, 2018 - 15:45</pubDate>
            <dc:creator>HHS Press Office</dc:creator>

        </item>
    </channel>
</rss>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

XPath 3.1 has a function [`parse-ietf-date`](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions-31/#func-parse-ietf-date). You should be able to use with feeds have RFC822 format dates. For instance with Saxon 9.8 and `doc('http://www.kuechenstud.io/lagedernation/feed/mp3/')//pubDate/parse-ietf-date(.)` I get a sequence of `xs:dateTime` values. The format in your sample (e.g. `Tuesday, April 24, 2018 - 15:45`), however, neither passes through an RSS feed validator, nor does the mentioned function manage to parse it.

On the other hand it should be possible to parse it using [`analyze-string`](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions-31/#func-analyze-string) and to extract the components, then to build an `xs:dateTime`:

```
<xsl:value-of select="//pubDate/(let $result := analyze-string(., '[a-z]+,\s*([a-z]+)\s+([0-9]{1,2}),\s*([0-9]{4})\s*-\s*([0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2})', 'i') return xs:dateTime($result//*:group[@nr = 3] || '-' || format-number(index-of($month-names, $result//*:group[@nr = 1]), '00') || '-' || $result//*:group[@nr = 2] || 'T' || $result//*:group[@nr = 4] || ':00'))"
   separator="&#10;"/>
```

for your posted sample returns the time `2018-04-24T15:45:00`.

To format that `xs:dateTime` with `format-dateTime` you could use

which then outputs e.g. `2018-04-24 3:45 P.M.`.

A complete sample is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:math="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions/math"
    xmlns:map="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions/map"
    xmlns:array="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions/array"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs math map array"
    version="3.0">

  <xsl:param name="month-names"
    as="xs:string*"
    select="('January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December')"/>


  <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>

  <xsl:template match="pubDate">
      <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:value-of 
          select="let $result := analyze-string(., '[a-z]+,\s*([a-z]+)\s+([0-9]{1,2}),\s*([0-9]{4})\s*-\s*([0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2})', 'i') 
                  return format-dateTime(
                     xs:dateTime($result//*:group[@nr = 3] || '-' || format-number(index-of($month-names, $result//*:group[@nr = 1]), '00') || '-' || format-number($result//*:group[@nr = 2], '00') || 'T' || $result//*:group[@nr = 4] || ':00'),
                     '[Y0001]-[M01]-[D01] [h]:[m01] [PN]'
                  )"
       separator="&#10;"/>          
      </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

which at https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/nc4NzQ7/3 output the `pubDate` as `<pubDate>2018-04-24 3:45 P.M.</pubDate>`.

Comment: Thanks. I am new to XSLT and wrote like this but below code gives this error - Invalid dateTime value "2018-04-6T17:00:00" (Day must be two digits)

Comment: <xsl:template match="pubDate"> <xsl:variable name="month-names" select="'January','February','March','April','May','June','July','August','September','October','November','December'"/><xsl:value-of select="//pubDate/(let $result := analyze-string(., '[a-z]+,\s*([a-z]+)\s+([0-9]{1,2}),\s*([0-9]{4})\s*-\s*([0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2})', 'i') return xs:dateTime($result//*:group[@nr = 3] || '-' || format-number(index-of($month-names, $result//*:group[@nr = 1]), '00') || '-' || $result//*:group[@nr = 2] || 'T' || $result//*:group[@nr = 4] || ':00'))"     separator="&#10;"/>        
    </xsl:template>

Comment: Try changing `$result//*:group[@nr = 2]` to `format-number($result//*:group[@nr = 2], '00')`, in general the above is meant as an example on how to approach it, with date parsing it is difficult to suggest a solution when there is only one sample of input data and no precise description, you will have to refine that code in any case to cater for the formats you expect.

Comment: Worked. Thank you so much.